# Runtime checking that switch is exhaustive (when it's compile time exhaustive)

Tags: typescript, switch-statement

I have a `switch` statement that covers all the compile time possibilities but, since the value can be user supplied, I want handle unexpected values in runtime.

This seems to be a place where typescript's type inference is **too** good, it assigns type `never` (since from the compilers perspective this should never happen) and won't let me access any of its fields.

[Simplified example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Circle%20%3D%20%7B%20shape%3A%20%22circle%22%2C%20radius%3A%20number%20%7D%3B%0D%0Atype%20Rectangle%20%3D%20%7B%20shape%3A%20%22rectangle%22%2C%20length%3A%20number%2C%20width%3A%20number%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20area(shape%3A%20Circle%20%7C%20Rectangle)%3A%20number%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20switch%20(shape.shape)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20case%20%22circle%22%3A%20return%20Math.PI%20*%20shape.radius%20*%20shape.radius%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20case%20%22rectangle%22%3A%20return%20shape.length%20*%20shape.width%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20throw%20new%20Error(%60Unexpected%20shape%20'%24%7Bshape.shape%7D'%60)%3B%0D%0A%7D):

```
type Circle = { shape: "circle", radius: number };
type Rectangle = { shape: "rectangle", length: number, width: number };

function area(shape: Circle | Rectangle): number {
    switch (shape.shape) {
        case "circle": return Math.PI * shape.radius * shape.radius;
        case "rectangle": return shape.length * shape.width;
    }
    throw new Error(`Unexpected shape '${shape.shape}'`); // Error: Property 'shape' does not exist on type 'never'.
}
```

Is there an elegant way to fix the last line? (more elegant than casting to `any` or using subscript operator).

Comment: You're pretty much going to either need to use a type assertion (which you say is not elegant?) or change the signature of `area()` and widen `shape` to whatever you actually expect to get at runtime.  I think an assertion is probably the most elegant way of getting around the fact that you are possibly lying to the compiler about what you expect to see at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

this page offers a solution: 
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

Adapted for your example:

```
    type Circle = { shape: "circle", radius: number };
    type Rectangle =  { shape: "rectangle", length: number, width: number };

    function throwOnNever(x: {shape: string}): never {
        throw new Error(`Unexpected shape: ${x.shape}`);
    }

    function area(shape: Circle | Rectangle): number {    
        switch (shape.shape) {
            case "circle": return Math.PI * shape.radius * shape.radius;
            case "rectangle": return shape.length * shape.width;
            default: return throwOnNever(shape);
        }
    }
```

Comment: But now it's no longer compile-time exhaustive (if you comment out the `case "rectangle"` line, for example, there is no warning)... maybe OP doesn't care, though.

Comment: @jcalz I agree that if you'd leave out the `"rectangle"` line it's not exhaustive anymore. 
Yet OP's question  "Is there an elegant way to fix the last line? (more elegant than casting to any or using subscript operator)", combined with the assumption of the title merrits the suggested solution in my opinion.